# SQL sum result of count

Tags: sql

I want to sum results of count function.

Count result looks like:

```
1. 16
2. 32
3. 0
4. 12
```

and I want to sum it.

I tried

```
select sum(count(...)) ...
```

It is not working. Also the following:

```
select sum(du) from (select ... as du ..)
```

Not working either.

Comment: share your entire query

Comment: sum(count()) makes no sense - even if it worked, you'd just get the count, because the rows have already been aggregated. Probably the count needs to be in a subquery. Explain what you're actually trying to do though, there might be a better way.

Comment: @Nerf : which database you are using sql server or mysql

Answer (score 6):

You need calculate counts in inner query `select count(...) as cnt from ... group by ...`; you need to use an alias (for example `cnt`) to name the count so that you can reference it from the outer query:

```
select sum(a.cnt) 
  from (
          select count(...) as cnt 
          from ... 
          group by ...
       ) as a
```

Comment: @Nerf also sql syntax could be slightly different in different DBs? What db are you using?